# what does it mean to "betray contempt for" someone?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I came across this phrase in a quotation from Carl Sagan, "they betray contempt for the intelligence of their customers".

From the context, it seems to mean "to show contempt", but I couldn't parse why betray and contempt are used together.

Edit: How does the meaning work out?

Comment: I expect it is an error introduced in the editing or typesetting process, replacing the intended word "portray" (to show) with "betray".

Comment: Have you looked up *betray* in the dictionary? The noun in the sentence could be *contempt* or any other depending on context. See also: [ell.se]

Comment: "works that presume that some people are and ought to be "better" than others betray contempt for those others ..." //  "his cavalier attitude about the responsibilities of his office seems to betray a contempt for the U.S. Constitution and the principles it embodies."  (both internet) Even signs of countification, never mind the licensing of the DO 'contempt' with 'betray'.

Comment: I looked online for half an hour before posting this question, and could not find any references to this phrase. So I don't think the question can be answered using **commonly-available references**. @Kris I understand that "_the noun in the sentence could be anything_", but the question is about how the meaning works out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually you'd conceal your contempt for a customer. "Betraying" contempt, then, is revealing it when you are meant to keep it hidden, like betraying a secret. Look at definition four of "betray" from [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/betray?show=0&t=1407904060):

4.

- to reveal unintentionally
- show, indicate
- to disclose in violation of confidence

Comment: Wow, amazing. Whenever, I think I've grasped how far the English language stretches, I log on to stack exchange to have something new (like this) surprise me and enhance my understanding of the langugage. Awesome!

Answer (score -1):

I expect it is an error introduced in the editing or typesetting process, replacing the intended word "portray" (to show) with "betray".